# Java 8 Threads with CompletableFuture: Shutdown after supplyAsync()?

Tags: java

Suppose I'm running an async thread as follows,

```
SubmissionSupplier supplier = new SubmissionSupplier();
SubmissionConsumer consumer = new SubmissionConsumer();
CompletableFuture<Void> completableFuture = 
   CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier).thenAccept(consumer);
// END, No further code
```

Do I need to do any shutdown to prevent memory leaks after this block? When I was using `ExecutorService` I had to do `service.shutdown()`.

Comment: You can still use an executor service here (`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier, service)`)... The fork-join pool is used by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. If you don't provide an executor to `supplyAsync` then it uses the [fork-join common pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) which does not need to be started or stopped. In fact, it *can't* be stopped.

> This pool is statically constructed; its run state is unaffected by attempts to `shutdown()` or `shutdownNow()`.